# datatables, default selected input (select) does not filter table

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm messing around with laravel and datatables and everything has been fine... until now. I hope some of you might be able to help me :)

I got a Select dropdown menu, that search one of the columns in the datatable (on change). The filtering  works fine, except the default value on pageload.

The datatable does not filter on pageload. The default value from the Select menu does not work and I cant find a solution for this and it's starting to drive me crazy.

My dropdown/select:

```html
<select class="ml-2" id="filter_effect">
    @foreach($effects as $effect)
        <option value="{{ $effect->title }}"
                @if($effect->id == $configurator->motor->effect_id)
                selected
                @endif
        >{{ $effect->title }} kW</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Datatables code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table =  $('#changeMotorForm').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
        ]}
    });

    $('#filter_effect').on('change', function () {
        table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
    });
});
```

Just to make it clear. The filtering of the datatable works fine, out of the box. Same with the select input filtering - works great. It's the default value that is causing problems. It does not filter/search the datatable on pageload, only when I select another `<option>`.

**UPDATE: Working code:**

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var table =  $('#changeMotorForm').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [
               { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
            ]
        });

        table.columns(1).search( $('#filter_effect').val() ).draw();

        $('#filter_effect').on('change', function () {
            table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
        } );

    });

</script>
```

Comment: i see no `onload` event. so, it won't filter datatable. add filtering after datatable initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can apply filter soon after the DataTable initialization
var table =  $('#changeMotorForm').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
    ]}
});

table.columns(1).search( $('#filter_effect').val() ).draw();
OR make first option value none instead of real values.
so user can select to apply filter
```

Comment: This worked! Going to update my post with working code :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `initComplete`.

```
var table =  $('#changeMotorForm').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
    ],
    initComplete: function() {
        this.columns(1).search($('#filter_effect').val()).draw();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't get that to work. It breaks the table "draw". Only displaying a standard table now - no datatable. Will look into it more when I get home from work :)

Comment: I had to remove an erroneous curly bracket after the columnDefs square bracket. Maybe it was that?

Comment: Same result. No initial filtering on the table and the select menu has stopped working. The table is converted to datatables now though.